# How to setup transactional replication on dedicated server using AG database with auto failover

Tags: availability-groups, transactional-replication

My plan is i have One dedicated server for Transactional replication as subscriber. And two nodes in Availability Group. I want to replicate one availability database on primary as publisher. When there is automatic failover, the secondary node will become primary and continue the transactional replication to dedicated server. Is there any way to achive this plan?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1. Make sure that all secondary replicas in the AG are setup with synchronous commit, with automatic failover.
2. Have the replication agents connect with the listener of the AG.